# Firefox/Chrome style shortcuts for Opera

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, compatibility, opera

Opera ships with multiple keyboard shortcut profiles. Where is the Firefox-compatible profile?

Opera tends to open a mail client setup dialog when I try to search, and to do nothing when I try to switch tabs. This keeps interrupting what I'm trying to do, and I'd rather not retrain my muscle memory. Chrome has been much more convenient to use, keeping the usual shortcuts working (exceptions: Ctrl-Tab in MRU order, F6 which I'd expect to cycle between major ui areas).

While there's a lot that does work (such as Ctrl-LDJBS), I'd like the following to be ported: Ctrl-K then Alt-Enter, Ctrl-L then Alt-Enter, F6, Ctrl-PageUp/PageDown, Ctrl-Shift-PageUp/PageDown.

Comment: CTRL-TAB in Tab order can be achieved through the options menu. There's an option for that in the advanced options. But how the hell is it called "Firefox-compatible" now?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will have to create, modify or change these shortcuts yourself. 
Menu > Settings > Preferences (Ctrl F12) > Advanced tab > Shortcuts  > Edit... a duplicate of Opera Standard preferably, of Keyboard setup (shortcuts) or Mouse setup (gestures). Then you'll have to search for the desired "Actions" or "Input", and reorder the shortcuts, etc. [See here.](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/add-modify-keyboard-shortcut) If the going gets tough consult [my.opera.com](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/forum.dml?id=28) In fact, - consult right away ! ;-)